# zoom to div with javascript

Tags: javascript, zooming

I have a page that contains hundreds of Divs with text inside. All divs are positioned with absolute coordinate. the page is very big, and can not be displayed on a normal monitor. I would like that on pageload the page is zoomed out, so you see the entire page, the texts will be so small that you cannot read it. Then after a timeout it should zoom in towards a specified div, based on it's ID value.

Can this be done?

I understand i can use this for the inital zoom out:

```
document.body.style.zoom=0.5;this.blur();
```

but how do i zoom in to a specified item?

edit: I was not clear enough, i apologzie: once zoomed out, i want to zoom in, with a zoom motion, so the user knows where the zoomed div is located. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may work for your request...

```js
$('.myDiv').click(function() {
  var top = '100px';
  var left = '50px';
  $('body').animate({zoom: '100%', scrollTop: top, scrollLeft: left});
});
```

```css
body {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  zoom: 100%;
}
body.out {
  zoom: 50%;
}
.myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body class="out">
  <div class="myDiv"></div>
  <div class="myDiv"></div>
  <div class="myDiv"></div>
  <div class="myDiv"></div>
  <div class="myDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry, i might not have been clear enough, I apologize. added an edit to the main question.

Comment: zoom part works, but the scrolling part does not. it allways zooms to the top left corner..

Comment: zoom seems to reset the scroll.. i cannot do it toghether.. it only works if i first zoom and then scroll, but then i loose the information where it is scrolling to.